# Compare selected form values?

Tags: javascript

I have two select fields and I want to compare them so if they both equal United States then alert the user.

Here is what I have but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(document.getElementById('country_o').value == "United States" AND document.getElementById('country_d').value == "United States") {
    window.alert("BOTH US!");
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it like this?

```
if(document.getElementById('country_o').value == "United States" && document.getElementById('country_d').value == "United States") 
{
    window.alert("BOTH US!");
}
```

where **AND** is replaced by **&&**

Answer (score 1):

The `AND` operator is `&&`.

And to get the selected element on a `SELECT` element use the index:

```
document.getElementById('country_o')
    .options[document.getElementById('country_o').selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I think it should be && not AND.  If you're getting a script error, that's likely your problem.  Note that & would probably also work, but I believe && is the logical and & is bitwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
    var select1 = document.getElementById("country_o");
    var select2 = document.getElementById("country_d");
    if (select1.value === select2.value === "United States") {
        // alert user
    }
})();
```